# Can my car sit on raised Jack stands for 20 year?

Tags: dodge

I have a 1992 dodge stealth that has been sitting on Jack stands  since I could walk, so more or less  14 years . I'm a junior in high school and my plans for the car are to get the car back in "running" state . Would this long term Jack stand period cause any body or chassis damage if jacked correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Time will be the real problem - fluids evaporating, degrading, leaving residues, metal rusting due to humidity etc etc

It depends on how, or if, it was prepared for storage...

But leaving on stands should not increase the issues.

Comment: Gasoline evaporating from a carburetor can plug it up in a few years. Nothing good can happen in the gas tank. I would try to drain gasoline from any item even now. Tires are another potential problem , letting air ( oxygen pressure) may help. i can't imagine any problem with the chassis.

Comment: Tires will be throw-away items after 14 years anyway, so there's no point doing anything with them till you are actively working on the car. Just be careful not to take the car off the jacks and onto flat tires! The only issue with the jacks may be that (depending where it is stored) the jacks may now have corroded themselves "stuck" onto the chassis, unless you put plenty of grease on the jacking points before you mothballed the car.